# Some text coming up white in Firefox on Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I am running Firefox version 3.0.11 on Ubuntu 9.04 on some websites, Stack family included, some text appears white and against a black background makes it invisible. If I highlight the text it comes back to its normal color for a little bit, some of the time. The text on some of the tags below is an example of my problem. What can I do to attempt to fix this.

[image]

**UPDATE:** White text was still present after starting in safe mode, as well as without desktop effects. Is there any other information I can give to help with the diagnosis?

Answer (score 1):

I am also running Firefox version 3.0.11 on Ubuntu 9.04

In your screenshot the text on some tags is obviously white and I never saw this effect
with my setup. My first guess would be that this is the effect of on of your Firefox extensions. I'd start Firefox in safe mode an see if the effect persists.

Comment: I'm runnung the same setup and I have also not seen this.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I tried safemode but it still persisted

Answer (score 1):

this is what i did for the same problem went to Edit/preferences/content under fonts & colors click the colors... button uneselect use system colors and also unselect allow pages to choose their own colors, instead of my selections i have mine set to text to a red and background to a black because my typing for some resion is white... and i cant see to good.

if for somereson you cant see something on a website such as on you-tube the vote button just select allow pages to choose their own  colors... hope this works for you...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using XGL too? If so, then try to turn off desktop effects and look if it is fixed. I had some problems with effects: text doesn't updates when scrolling, so now I'm working without them.

Comment: All my desktop effects have already been turned off and the problem still exists, thanks though